# Error when placing a shape inside a for-loop in JavaFX

Tags: java, for-loop, javafx

The program executes fine if I just add one `circle` to  `Group scene2`. However, when I add it inside a `for-loop`, the second stage didn't show up(error). The way I want to design the application is that when user enter an even number on first stage press the button,the second stage should appear with number of circles the user entered.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> xaxis = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> yaxis = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static int x = 150, y = 200;
Scene scene, scene2;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Group root = new Group();
        TextField text = new TextField();
        
        Button button = new Button("Start");
        button.setLayoutY(25);
        root.getChildren().addAll(text,button);
        scene = new Scene(root,400,200);
        
        Group root2 = new Group();
        
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(text.getText());
            compute(a);
            for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                root2.getChildren().add(getCircle(i));
            }
            scene2 =  new Scene(root2, 400, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
        });
        
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**My compute method and getCircle**

```
public static void compute(int a) {
    xaxis.add(x);
    yaxis.add(y);
    int b = a/2;
    
    for(int i = 1; i < b; i++) {
        x += 20;
        xaxis.add(x);
        yaxis.add(y);
    }
    
    y+=50;
    x=140;
    
    for(int i = 1; i < b; i++) {
        x -= 20;
        xaxis.add(x);
        yaxis.add(y);
    }
    
}

public Circle getCircle(int c) {
    Circle circle = new Circle(xaxis.get(c), yaxis.get(c), 10);
    return circle;
}
```

Comment: btw: static scope is (nearly) always wrong - definitely here. And please provide a [mcve] when asking for debugging help (this here seems near, but why the external block for creating the circles? Please edit to show it in context ..

Answer (score 0):

In java the index of the first element in an `ArrayList` is zero and not one. You need to change the `for` loops in method `compute()`. Compare your `compute()` method to the code below.

```java
public static void compute(int a) {
    xaxis.add(x);
    yaxis.add(y);
    int b = a/2;

    for(int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        x += 20;
        xaxis.add(x);
        yaxis.add(y);
    }

    y+=50;
    x=140;

    for(int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        x -= 20;
        xaxis.add(x);
        yaxis.add(y);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
If you debug your code, you will see that because you start the `for` loops from 1 (one) and not 0 (zero), `xaxis` and `yaxis` contain one less element than desired. For example, if you enter 2 (two) into the `TextField`, then `xaxis` and `yaxis` each contain one element. Then in your event handler you try to extract two circles but you can't, because `xaxis` and `yaxis` only contain one element. Hence the error you are getting, namely

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

And in method `getCircle()` you are indexing into the `ArrayList`.

Comment: i dont use ```int i = 1``` as an indexing to arraylist, i use it solely for looping only